# Have a list, need a DataFrame to use `loc` to lookup rows by column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pull out the rows from these CSVs where the state is "Pennsylvania": https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us

I have this code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

df = []

path = "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/git/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']
    print(row)
```

I'm getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'`

I understand that it's expecting a DataFrame but I've set `df` as a list.  But I don't know how to make it a DataFrame so that my pattern matching works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `df` is the empty list `[]` that you define at the beginning, not a Pandas DataFrame. Did you forget to load the data:

```
path = "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/git/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)   # this line???
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']
    print(row)
```

Comment: ...Is it obvious that I haven't used Python in a while?